# How to use downloaded templates (.sketch files) in android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I had downloaded some free templates from http://sketchappsources.com/ and all of them are .sketch files. I had search thru the net for instructions but none of the results suit me.

How could I import those .sketch file in android studio to turn them into my xml design? I am a Windows user and i saw a lot solution that is work in Mac only.

Thank you.

Comment: I think the only way for you now is to look at the sketch layout and create an xml version from the scratch. BTW you can run Hackintosh on windows using Virtual Box etc.

Comment: https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/here-s-how-you-can-preview-your-sketch-designs-on-android-phone-d4584d13b722#.rsnbj6cnr This link may help.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a step-by-step guide on how you can start previewing your designs on your Android devices.

Step 1 : Download the Sketch Preview plugin from this link. (freeware). Download Skala Preview for Mac from this link. (freeware). Download Skala View for your Android device from this link. (freeware)

Step 2 : Install Sketch Preview plugin by clicking on Plugins menu and selecting Reveal Plugins Folder. Unzip your Sketch Preview plugin files and paste them in the folder that had opened by Reveal Plugins Folder command. Restart Sketch. On restarting you will get 2 new options in Plugins menu. a) Preview b) Preview Setup. Read the documentation on the plugin page to get an in-depth understanding of Preview Setup.

Step 2 : Install Skala Preview on your Mac and Skala view on your Android device

Step 3 : Connect Skala Preview and Skala View. To do this make sure that your Mac and Android device are on same wi-fi network. In your Skala view on your Android device, click on the monitor/tv icon and select your Mac. When you do that you will be prompted to authorize the device on your Mac in Skala Preview app. Approve the authorisation.

Step 4 : Preview your design on your device by selecting the artboard that you want to preview and pressing ⌘P. This will push your artboard to Skala Preview on your Mac, which will sync it with your Android device. Everytime you update your design, press ⌘P and see the live preview of your updated design on your device.

At times there are problems in syncing the designs between Mac and Android device. If this happens with you, just go ahead and click on monitor/tv icon again on your Android device and select your Mac again and everything should work just fine.